# Add letters to image source through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, gallery

In my photo gallery I have it so on click of an image it just changes the larger image to the source of it. But now I want the onclick function of the image to take the source that it would originally inject into the image and add 3 letters to the end before injecting, "lrg".

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setImg(a){
              document.getElementById('ImageFrame').src = 
                          a.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src
            } 
        </script>
```

Html image that you click.

```
<a href="#gallery" onclick="setImg(this);"><img class="gallery" src="JCF/PICT0421.jpg" 

/></a>
```

Larger image that changes:

```
<div>
           <img id="ImageFrame" src="JCF/PICT0422.jpg" width="500" />
</div>
```

When the link injects into the "imageframe" I want the source to change to JCF/PICT0421lrg.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got it right, this will solve our problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setImg(a){
              var arr = a.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src.split(".");
              document.getElementById('ImageFrame').src = arr[0]+"lrg"+"."+arr[1];
            } 
        </script>
```

extended example
http://jsfiddle.net/ymutlu/E9Fq5/

Comment: PERFECT!! Thank you so much I've been trying this for so long...I will accept the answer when it lets me in 9 minutes.

Comment: I did but it said I had to wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

In change `setImg` to

```
function setImg(a){
    var file_parts = a.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src.split(".");
    var new_name = file_parts[0] + "lrg." + file_parts.slice(1).join(".");
    document.getElementById('ImageFrame').src = new_name;
}
```

This will add the "lrg" before the first dot in the filename.